# Dijkstra algorithm with negative weigths

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Heres an implementation of dijkstra algo i found in an online couse. Can anyone site an example with negative edges where this might not work.

```
vector<edge> adj[100];
vector<int> dist(100, INF);

void dijkstra(int start) {
    dist[start] = 0;
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>,
    vector<pair<int, int> >,
    greater<pair<int, int> > > pq;
    pq.push(make_pair(dist[start], start));
    while (!pq.empty()) {
         int u = pq.top().second,
         d = pq.top().first;
         pq.pop();
    if (d > dist[u]) continue;
    for (int i = 0; i < adj[u].size(); i++) {
    int v = adj[u][i].v,
    w = adj[u][i].weight;
    if (w + dist[u] < dist[v]) {
        dist[v] = w + dist[u];
        pq.push(make_pair(dist[v], v));
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45129276/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/77997/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Dijsktra's algorithm includes a visited set which means that we can avoid revisiting nodes, and can terminate as soon as the destination has been visited.

This implementation does not use such a set.  This means that it may revisit nodes and adjust the distance if it reduces.

The good thing is that this will always return the correct answer if it terminates.  However, the algorithm can take a long time to terminate if negative weights are included (in particular, if there is a negative weight loop then this algorithm will never terminate).

Comment: well i had the impression that negative weight loops are not considered in shortest path problem because then technically the shortest path is negative infinity. And if there is no loop then it will take almost the same time as that implemented using visited set because of the condition "if (d > dist[u]) continue;" So can we conclude that if no negative cycles are there its better than bellmann-ford and will give the correct answer.

Comment: in practice it would expect it to be better, but be warned that it is possible to construct graphs where it takes exponential time to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

The example is **cycle with negative weight**. Dijkstra's algorithms never leaves this cycle.

[image]